# Reading CSV File using Entiry Framework 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, entity-framework-4

Is it possible to read CSV file  using Entiry Framework 4 such that it should give me an entity that I can use it normally within my application?

Thanks

Comment: this is something I would love to see. We process quite large csv files in our organization every day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that there is a CSV adapter for EF4, but you could always use a [Linq-to-CSV concept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericwhite/linq-to-text-and-linq-to-csv) for small CSV files.  The results of your queries could be mapped into your EF objects and written to tables or just used in your data access layer as an additional data source.

Comment: As my CSV file is not more then 25 rows, I think this solution works. Thanks for suggestion.